# Return non matching values of provided list

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table USR

```
user_name     User_id
Abcd             1
Abce             2
Abcf             3
```

Now if I hit a query like

```
Select user_name from USR where user_name IN ('Abcd','Abce','Abcg','Avfd','Asdf')
```

I get an output

```
Abcd
Abce
```

Now what if I want this output of non matching parameters.

```
Abcg
Avfd
Asdf
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Edit: I dont have access to create anything & only can do DQL

Answer (score 0):

How about make a new table Temp

```
abcd
abce
abcg
avfd
asdf
```

then

```
Select user_name from Temp where user_name NOT IN USR
```

Comment: Nice but I already told I cant create anything...so no tables

Comment: i doubt there's a way to do that with out making a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Your original query:

```
SELECT user_name 
FROM usr
WHERE user_name IN ('Abcd','Abce','Abcg','Avfd','Asdf')
  ;
```

To invert the logic, just add "NOT" :

```
SELECT user_name 
FROM usr
WHERE user_name NOT IN ('Abcd','Abce','Abcg','Avfd','Asdf')
  ;
```

Oops, it appears you want it the other way around: (the solution can need other syntax, depending on your DBMS/ SQL-dialect) This syntax for Postgresql is via a CTE:

```
WITH zzz(zname) AS (
        VALUES ('three'),('four'), ('five')
        )
SELECT * FROM zzz
        WHERE zzz.zname NOT IN (select zname FROM usr)
        ;
```

Generate some data:

```
SET search_path='tmp';
DROP TABLE usr;
CREATE TABLE usr
        ( id INTEGER NOT NULL
        , zname varchar
        );
INSERT INTO usr(id,zname) VALUES
 ( 1, 'one'),( 2, 'two')
,( 3, 'three'),( 4, 'four')
        ;
```

results:

```
SET
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 4
 zname 
-------
 five
(1 row)
```

Comment: I think you're missing the point - the way I read it he wants to output the user_names from the IN clause not the USR table.

Comment: @wildplasser :- Your query will return 'Abcf' only, Goran is right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using can use SQL Server 2008 TV Constructors:

```
SELECT user_name 
FROM (VALUES('Abcd'),('Abce'),('Abcg'),('Avfd'),('Asdf')) AS Q(user_name)

EXCEPT

SELECT [USER_NAME]
FROM #USER
```

This should work with any RDBMS (I think):

```
SELECT 'Abcd' AS [user_name]
UNION SELECT 'Abce' 
UNION SELECT 'Abcg'
UNION SELECT 'Avfd'
UNION SELECT 'Asdf'

EXCEPT

SELECT [user_name]
FROM #USER
```